# git send-email thows Errno architecture (..) does not match executable architecture (...) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Errno.pm line 11

Tags: linux, git, perl

So I needed to send a patch into the linux kernel and installed *git email* on my fedora machine.

However, for the life of me I can't figure why when I just even do this:

```
[gideon@gideon-fedora linus_tree]$ git send-email
```

I get:

```
Errno architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.4.9-300.fc23.x86_64) does not match executable architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.7.9-200.fc24.x86_64) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Errno.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 28.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 28.
```

So if I do `perl -V` I get:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 22 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=4.7.9-200.fc24.x86_64, 
    archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux buildhw-05.phx2.fedoraproject.org 
    4.7.9-200.fc24.x86_64 #1 
    smp thu oct 20 14:26:16 utc 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
```

BUT if I do this `$ uname -r` I get: `4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64`

Yes I am playing with kernels and I did do a make and make install of the latest **4.10-rc** kernel.

Any clues to how this happened? I tried reinstalling perl and reinstalling git mail.

Comment: Does `perl -e 'use Errno'` trigger the same error? I don't think this is git related.

Comment: Yes :( that causes the same error. Man that was silly. What should I do. I've tried reinstalling perl already?

Comment: `Errno` is a core perl module but maybe Fedora packages it separately. Is there a `perl-Errno` package or similar?

Comment: @melpomene oh wow! It worked. I just did `dnf upgrade perl-Errno` and it worked. Thanks so much. You could add your comments as an answer and I could accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't look git specific. You can use `perl -e 'use Errno'` to confirm that it triggers the same error all by itself.

You mentioned that you tried reinstalling perl, but despite `Errno` being a core module, Fedora packages it separately as `perl-Errno`.

Upgrading `perl-Errno` should fix the version mismatch between it and perl.